# Properly handling exceptions in Python and exit class execution

Tags: python

How to handle inside class execution errors? return something so an outside function knows that and call the class with other data. What will be the proper way to do this in Python?

I understand we can handle all exceptions by doing the following:

```
import sys
try: 
    do_something()
except Exception:
    do_something_else()
    system.exit('Something happened')
```

and the line "`system.exit('Something happened')`" will exit Python. 
The thing is that I have a class, with three methods plus the `__init__()` method. In total four methods or functions. And I have a function that calls this **class** with different values and the class performs its actions. I'm not doing any exception handling in the class because I have no idea how to do so.
Here's what my class looks like.

```
class myClass:
   def __init__(self, values, more values):
      config = []
      answer = self.first_method(values)
      if answer == True:
         self.third_method(values, more_values, answer)
   def first_method(values):
      my_tuple = self.second_method(values)
      return my_tuple
   def second_method(values)
      do_stuff
      return stuff
   def third_method(values, more_values, answer):
      do_stuff...
```

outside function will look like:

```
from my myclass import myClass
def my_function():
    count = 0
    more_values = [6,7,8,9,10]
    list_of_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for values in list_of_values:
        myClass(values, more_values)
        count += 1
```

and what I need is that, if something happens in the `first_method()`, `second_method()`, and `third_method()`.I will need the class to be stopped and return something so the outside function will know that the class has been stopped by something and skip that one and try next one. Did I make myself clear enough? 
I don't show the code from my class because I'm still working on the class itself and also the outside function. But that's the main idea.

Something that might be important: What I'm trying to perform is to create some images and I'm using PIL. I've been importing the following:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageOps, ImageDraw
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything more than setting up the class in the `__init__` method in the first place. You're now handling all the logic there as well, in which case you'd basically be better off using a function instead (that calls the other functions). In particular, you're other 3 methods don't use `self` (in fact, `self`` as the usual first argument isn't even in these methods). You may want to read up more about how to use classes in Python. Or, in your case, when to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment about avoiding classes where you don't really need them, try going about it this way:

```
def start(values, more values):
   config = []
   answer = runfirst(values)
   if answer == True:
      runthird(values, more_values, answer)

def runfirst(values):
   my_tuple = runsecond(values)
   return my_tuple

def runsecond(values):
   do_stuff
   return stuff

def runthird(values, more_values, answer):
   do_stuff...
```

Then, in your "outside" function:

```
from myfunctions import start
def my_function():
    count = 0
    more_values = [6,7,8,9,10]
    list_of_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for values in list_of_values:
        try:
            start(values, more_values)
        except (ValueError, IndexError) as exc:
            print("Houston, we've had a problem:", exc)
            continue
        count += 1
```

No class necessary: all your first, second and third functions are stowed away neatly in their own module, and don't need a class.

Note: never catch *every* exception with the generic `except Exception`. Catch specific exceptions. Because there is always that one exception you overlooked that you really want to bubble up all the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "try", "except", and "raise" together: try the inside function stuffs, if it causes exception, throw it to the outside function with "raise", then on the outside function try to call the first function, if it raises an exception move to the second one and so on.

Your code, Class and functions are quite messed up, so I'll try to make a more generic answer (you will need to handle **init** function by yourself)

```
class myClass:
   def __init__(self, values, more_values):
      config = []
      """answer = self.first_method(values)
      if answer == True:
         self.third_method(values, more_values, answer)"""
   def first_method(self, values):
      print "executing first function"
      try:
          stuff = "stuff"
          #my_tuple = self.second_method(values)
          x = 5/0 #causing an exception
          return stuff
      except Exception as e:
          raise(e)
   def second_method(self, values):
      print "executing second function"
      try:
          #do_stuff
          stuff = "stuff"
          x = 5/0 #causing an exception
          return stuff
      except Exception as e:
          raise(e)
   def third_method(self, values, more_values, answer):
       print "executing third function"
       try:
           #do_stuff...
           stuff = "stuff"
           x = 5/0 #causing an exception
           return stuff
       except Exception as e:
           raise(e)
```

The outside function:

```
def my_function():
    count = 0
    more_values = [6,7,8,9,10]
    list_of_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
    #for values in list_of_values:
    if(1 == 1):
        mc = myClass(values, more_values)
        #count += 1
        try:
            mc.first_method(values)
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                mc.second_method(values)
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    mc.third_method(values, more_values, "answer")
                except Exception as e:
                    print "My three functions have failed :-("
```